# BoxLayout can't be shared error, trying to fit two JPanels in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Trying to have 2 panels in a frame, one small one at the top and one filling up the rest of the frame. This code returns a "BoxLayout can't be shared" error though.

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Clients");
        frame.setSize(1000,900);

        JPanel sorters = new JPanel();
        sorters.setSize(1000, 100);
        frame.getContentPane().add(sorters);

        JPanel rowPane = new JPanel();
        JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(rowPane, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrPane.setSize(1000, 800);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrPane);

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Comment: Please search before asking. A simple search on [BoxLayout can't be shared](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+boxlayout+can%27t+be+shared) brings any and all the links that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BoxLayout` must have as first parameter the actual container it is applied to, in your case the container is the contentPane of the frame :

```
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```